# Append remote IP in a rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rules

i would like to retrieve in a querystring, the remote ip via a simple rewrite rule, is it possible ?

thanks in advance

here is the sample

RewriteCond Host: [www.host.com](http://www.host.com)

RewriteRule (.*)/test.html $1/test.php?IP=**%{REMOTE_ADDR}** [R,L]